# How to change a form submit style to both click and enter

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux

I've build a search bar inside of a nav bar. The button is the magnifying glass inside the search bar. I moved it inside the input field using CSS. Everything works if the button is clicked. Text is cleared, the /search page renders and search index shown. When I hit enter, the search text clears, but nothing else. I've added two functions searchKeyPress(e) and handleSearch(), none of which work. How do I make it search on enter?

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


class SearchBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            searchItem: "",
        };
        this.update = this.update.bind(this);
        this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);
    }

    update() {
        return e => this.setState({ searchItem: e.currentTarget.value });
    }

    searchKeyPress(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            document.getElementById('search-button').click();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    handleSearch() {   
        document.getElementById("search-input")
            .addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
            // event.persist();
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                document.getElementById("search-button").click();
            }
        });
        this.setState( {
            searchItem: "",
        })
    };

    render() {

        return (
            <div id="search-form">
                <form >
                    <input //onKeyDown={this.searchKeyPress}
                        type="text"
                        id="search-input"
                        placeholder="Search videos"
                        value={this.state.searchItem}
                        onChange={this.update()}
                    />
                    <button type="submit" id="search-button" onClick={this.handleSearch}>
                        <Link to={`/search?search=${this.state.searchItem}`}><img id="search-icon" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/49/49116.svg" alt="" /></Link>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For this problem input type="search" solves the problem. If your input type is search, it will send the query when pressed enter and the input is focused.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();  // Hold the form submit
  // get the updated state here and do what ever you want with that state
}
```

**Explanation:** On input change you are already updating the value in state using `update` method. So you just have to handle the form submit (either done by click of enter button or mouse click on submit button) and under that method you can get the updated state and use it in your own way to make an api call etc. And with this you don't need `handleSearch` and `searchKeyPress` methods.

Comment: could you please provide an example

Answer (score 0):

I think you should perform the onSubmit event in Form, same as you did onClick on button element.